# Ambiguous request for Actions in MVC where Actions have different names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two Actions in my controller with different names but when I try to send data to the second, I get an error saying:

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'HouseholdController' is ambiguous between the following action
>   methods: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Find(Int32) on type
>   WhatWorks.Controllers.HouseholdController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(Int32) on type WhatWorks.Controllers.HouseholdController

Every other question on this that I've found has been to do with the Actions having the same name. I can't work out where I'm going wrong although there may be a better way to accomplish what I'm trying...

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
{
    int pagesize = 10;
    var model = GetDisplay().OrderBy(i => i.familyId);
    return View(model.ToPagedList(page, pagesize));
}

//
// GET: /HouseholdSearch/

public ActionResult Search()
{
    return PartialView("Find");
}

[HttpParamAction]
public ActionResult Find(int Id)
{
    var model = GetDisplay().TakeWhile(m => m.familyId == Id);
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

**Partial View "Find"**

```
@using BootstrapSupport
@model WhatWorks.ViewModels.HouseholdListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.familyId, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.familyId, new { @class = "input-mini" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.familyId, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="Find" class="btn ">Search</button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**HTTPParamAction Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Reflection;

public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your HttpParamAction attribute code? I think that's the issue -- I assume that's an ActionNameSelectorAttribute, and it's responding that "Index" is a valid name for that action.

Comment: Have you defined any custom routes?

Comment: @JacobM I've added the code above. It is [from here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479946)

Comment: @zimdanen No custom routes are defined. The [HTTPPost] attribute as suggested by p.s.w.g is working insofar as it hits the correct action but it just loops around the Find action when it should go to the Index view.

Comment: Perhaps because the button has `name="Find"`, that's causing the line in the HttpParamActionAttribute that says `return request[methodInfo.Name] != null` to return true.  That is, request["Find"] isn't null, so the Find method reports that it is a match.

Comment: I've realised I was over-complicating a simple process. I've added an answer. Thanks for the pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've amended the BeginForm to explicitly reference the Find action and this is working without any extra attributes.

I think I was just expecting a more complicated solution!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Find", "Household"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` or `[HttpPost]` attribute to your find method:

```
[HttpParamAction]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Find(int Id)
{
    var model = GetDisplay().TakeWhile(m => m.familyId == Id);
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I'm getting another error which is probably related. I'll work on it and post a new question if needed.

Comment: The new error is due to the call to the "Index" view coming straight back to the Find Action. I can't work out why this is happening when the Actions have unique names.