# Multiple submits on MVC view when hidden value is needed for each - best practice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I've got a view with multiple submit buttons, and I don't know what the best way to handle this is. At the moment one of my controller actions looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult SaveAlbum(
    string saveButton,
    string createButton,
    string deleteButton,
    string showButton,
    string myHiddenValue)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveButton))
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(createButton))
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    // repeat for all buttons

    var viewModel = new MyViewModel(one, two, three);

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

This looks pretty terrible. I'm assuming the best way would be to have a separate form for each submit button, which posts to different actions, but as it only posts what's inside the form and I need `myHiddenValue` for all of them I don't know what I should do. Should I use multiple hidden values instead? The hidden value is a comma separated list of values for all the checked checkboxes (added with jQuery).

Comment: check this - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=705

Comment: Systematix Infotech - that is exactly what I have done above.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally all your submits should go to individual Action methods on controller.

**[Update]**
A quick search on stackoverflow gives following links:

- [ASP.Net MVC 4 Form with 2 submit buttons/actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479946/asp-net-mvc-4-form-with-2-submit-buttons-actions)
- http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629717/how-to-use-multiple-submit-button-in-mvc

Comment: Yes, like I said that's what I assume but I don't know what to do when I need the hidden value for each of them. I updated the title of my question so it's clearer.

Comment: Ideally, any submit action on the form should submit entire form. So you should get it. I don't have any working sample for the same though.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy

suppose you have two buttons

```
 <input type="button" name="btnSave"  value="Save"/>
 <input type="button" name="btnSave"  value="Update" />
```

your controller

```
  public ActionResult SaveAlbum(string btnSave)
```

if u click on Save, value of btnSave will be "Save" and if u click on Update button, value of btnSave at controller will be "Update". so give the save name to all your button but different values.

Comment: This would still mean only one controller action and I'd have to check for the value of the button to know what code to run.

Comment: you can redirect from controller to your desired action after checking the value.

Comment: and if you want to redirect directly from view then you have to write script and change then action of your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnUpdate').click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(form).attr("action", "Update");
   $(form).submit();
});

public ActionResult Update(string btnSave)

$('#btnSave').click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(form).attr("action", "Save");
   $(form).submit();
});

public ActionResult Save(string btnSave)
```