# Multiple dynamic Submitbuttons in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently developing a Framework to generate dynamic Views in MVC, the idea is based on this [tutorial](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/04/23/generating-aspnet-mvc-view-controls-according-to-xml-configurations/).

The next step is adding the possibility to generate multiple submit buttons but I cant get it to work. I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479946/asp-net-mvc-4-form-with-2-submit-buttons-actions) approach. However, since i want to generate those buttons dynamically, this does not work yet.

What I tried is to modify this attribute code here:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);

        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
            isValidName = true;
        }

        return isValidName;
    }
}
```

While debugging I digged down the ValueProvider and found out that the JQueryFormValueProvider in the Collection of Valueproviders actually contains the Name of the clicked submitbutton.

The button is generated like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="buttonClick:@Model.Id" value="@Model.Text" />
```

[image: Here is the Value i am looking for]

Unfortunately the ValueProviders do not let me Iterate through the Keys so I dont know how to get the value I circled red in the above screenshot.
It doesnt need to be this approach, all what counts is, to find out which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution by modifying the Attribute-code like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class NameToRouteDataAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    /// <Summary>Name of the Value you want to grab from the control.</Summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        ValueProviderCollection providers = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider as ValueProviderCollection;

        if (providers != null)
        {
            // We need this value-Provider as it contains the Data from the Form
            JQueryFormValueProvider formProvider = providers.OfType<JQueryFormValueProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (formProvider != null)
            {
                // now look for the specified value-prefix.
                var kvp = formProvider.GetKeysFromPrefix(Name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (kvp.Key != null)
                    controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = kvp.Key;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Contollercode:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [NameToRouteDataAttribute(Name = "buttonClick")]
    public ActionResult Show(FormViewModel form)
    {
        string buttonId = RouteData.GetRequiredString("buttonClick");

        ...
    }
```

Buttoncode

```
@model MvcForms.Controls.ButtonViewModel
<input type="submit" name="buttonClick.@Model.Id" value="@Model.Text" />
```

The important thing here is, that the name of the Button contains a dot. This makes the JQueryFormValueProvider.GetKeysFromPrefix work the way I need it to.