# Capture textarea content when posting to Edit controller/view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model of type `List<ReviewGroupViewModel>` where `ReviewGroupViewModel` is:

```
public class ReviewGroupViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index.cshtml view, I iterate through this model using nested for-loops and build a table for each `ReviewGroupViewModel`, grouped by `ReviewGroupViewModel.Country`. I ultimately have a row in my table for each `Review` object. The `Commentary` field for each row is displayed using a `TextAreaFor` HTML helper, allowing users to enter text:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Review", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Country)</h6>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[i].Reviews[0].Commentary)
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: center">
                    Actions
                </th>
            </tr>
            @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].Reviews.Count; j++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].Reviews[j].Commentary)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { tempId = Model[i].Reviews[j].TempId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { tempId = Model[i].Reviews[j].TempId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
}
```

This is bounded by a form that is submitted on-click of a "save" button elsewhere on the page.

Now let's say a user types some text into one (or many) of the textareas in the Index view and then proceeds to click on "Edit" in the "Actions" for a given table row. This text is then lost as I'm simply passing an `Id` (type: int) to my Edit controller method. The question is, how do I not lose this entered text (for both this `Review` object and all others in the Index view) when navigating to other views for actions like editing/deleting?

AFAIK, you can't directly pass a complex object from a view to a controller method. You also obviously can't nest HTML forms. Surely this is a common scenario but how do I handle it in code?

Comment: But this is an edit form (your editing the `Commentary` property) so why are you navigating to a new view to edit it again?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the ActionLink. It generates a simple hyperlink. A hyperlink will send a GET request to the server. And you cannot put complex objects in the body of a GET request.

You need to do this:
[Form with 2 submit buttons/actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479946/asp-net-mvc-4-form-with-2-submit-buttons-actions)

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your 'for' loop should be placed into an editor template.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Review", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i], "MyTemplateName");
    }
}
```

Create a folder named **EditorTemplates** inside your View folder and create a View called ***MyTemplateName***. Inside it you have the code for each single item of the iteration by passing a single model to the view.

**MyTemplateName.cshtml**

```
@model Review

<h6>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Country)</h6>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Reviews[0].Commentary)
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: center">
                    Actions
                </th>
            </tr>
            @for (var j = 0; j < m.Reviews.Count; j++)
            {
                // Here you should have different editor template... see the pattern :)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Reviews[j], "MySecondTemplate")
            }
        </table>
```

Hope this information can help you.

Comment: Thanks George, got thrown off by the `@model Review` in your MyTemplateName.cshtml. I believe that should be `@model ReviewGroupViewModel` in my case?

Comment: In `MySecondTemplate` what would I be passing to the controller? I still won't be able to pass the object right?